# Group by value of record's in a column of table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and I need to `group` all the country details in the table as `count`.

```
customer id  city           country
----------------------------------
1            Hyderabad      India  
2            Tamilnadu      India
3            New York       USA
4            Los Angeles    USA
5            Sydney         Australia
```

I need the output as below - I need to count all the fields and display output.

```
India      2 
USA        2      
Australia  1
```

`India` is twice in the table,`USA` is 2 times in the table and `Australia` is once in the table.

Comment: `select count(city) cnt,country from tablename group by country`

Comment: Thanks a lot.........

Answer (score 0):

```
select country, count(*)
from your_table
group by country
```